# Powershell connect-microsoftteams mfa via userform generates unhandled exception

Tags: userform, unhandled-exception, multi-factor-authentication

Powershell connect-microsoftteams mfa via userform generates unhandled exception
Hi, I'm trying to create a gui frontend to a number of scripts to make them easier to access and use for colleagues . Some of the scripts require connections to O365 admins like connect-microsoftteams. At first the MFAs for the connects wouldn't even appear. Uncle google advised to use Powershell 7 when connecting through userforms. Which we installed and that did make the MFAs appear. However, when authenticating the MFA, I get a unhandled exception (an issue with the parameter 'session') and MFA browser window says 'Can't reach this page'. And the url of the MFA browser window is calling an odd localhost:..... url. clicking Continue on the unhandled exception does nothing

Outside of the gui, the connections work fine.

I've tried:

try-catch block, no change

&

netsh winhttp reset proxy, no change

thumbnail image 1 of blog post titled

```
                        Powershell connect-microsoftteams mfa via userform generates unhandled exception
```

Any ideas how I can get passed this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
Simply switch the default browser to MS Edge